# Library dependency problem with sphirewall-core and libboost

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

I am facing problems with library dependencies when trying to install `sphirewall-core`. Is there any way to solve this or to install that dependencies?

These are the steps I followed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sphirewall-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sphirewall-core : Depends: libboost-random1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libboost-regex1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libboost-serialization1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libboost-system1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libboost-thread1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libprocps0 (>= 1:3.3.2-1) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libboost-random1.49-dev but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can download  sphirewall-core sourcecode from svn repository hosted by BitBucket**
**Before that you need to install git on your system try this command on your terminal**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://bitbucket.org/sphirewalllabs/sphirewall-code.git
```

**source http://sphirewall.net/**

Comment: thank u Bipul kumar....... is it not possible to insall through debian installation?

Comment: Yes it is possible Try it, and let me know too :)

Comment: ya.. i tryed. from there only i got that error of dependency

Comment: i tryed below commands for debian installation

Comment: See this sphirewall-core does not exist in ubuntu repository. you can try to search from this command on your terminal sudo apt-cache search sphirewall-core

Comment: after executing that command am getting "sphirewall-core - Sphirewall Core Package" that's it..... any idea

Comment: Are you able to get the package details when you have executed this command "sudo apt-cache search sphirewall-core" ?? May i know which version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: no.. not getting. am getting just 'sphirewall-core - Sphirewall Core Package'